# Major styling problems moving from Chrome to IE11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The screen I am working on looks fine in Chrome, but when I open it up in IE11 it's a mess. I have been searching through old questions and can't seem to pinpoint the issue.

Chrome:

[image]

IE:

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
        <div>
            @Html.Label("NT User Id:", new { style = "font-size: medium" })
            @Html.Label("* ", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: medium" })
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Id, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 20, style = "border: none; font-size: 14px; width: 260px", placeholder = "NT User ID" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_Id, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Last Name:", new { style = "font-size: medium" })
        @Html.Label("* ", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: medium" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 50, style = "border: none; font-size: 14px; width: 260px", placeholder = "User Last Name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ddlNewUserHealthPlan" class="form-group" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div>
        @Html.Label("Health Plan:", new { style = "font-size: medium" })
        @Html.Label("* ", new { @class = "text-danger", style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: medium" })
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NewUserHealthPlans, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.GetHealthPlans(Model.HEALTHPLANLIST), "Select a Healthplan ---", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlNewUserHealthPlanSelect", style = "font-size: 14px; border: none; width: 260px; padding-bottom: 0" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewUserHealthPlans, String.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are relying pretty heavily on `Flexbox`. IE [has some bugs](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) when it comes to rendering Flebox items. Might be worth a shot to run your CSS [through a prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: @APAD1 This is a good tip. I need to learn more about this; thanks for the hint.

Comment: The issue is with flex as it is already suggested by another community member. If you are using min-width or max-width or length in your CSS then also it causes this issue. You can replace it with length or width may help to fix this issue. If the issue persists then I suggest you provide your code with simple HTML and CSS. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Is there any progress on this issue? If you had found the solution then please try to post it as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an acceptable answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. If the issue still persists then try to refer the suggestions on the thread and let us know about your status for this issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main fix for this ended up being to use a [prefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/), which solved many of the issues. However, I also ended up removing a lot of the Flexbox and using plain HTML and CSS. This allowed me to style the page as needed and deliver it in the time constraint I was working under.

Lesson learned: plan for this cross-browser compatibility ahead of time.